# multivariate probability generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

Suppose I have three random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$, with probability generating functions $g_1(z)$, $g_2(z)$ and $g_3(z)$. Now I have a joint-distribution $P(X_1-X_2,X_1-X_3)$, whose probability generating function is $G(z_1,z_2)$.

What is the relation between $G(z_1,z_2)$ and $g_1(z)$, $g_2(z)$, $g_3(z)$?

Comment: The $X_i$s are independent?

Comment: @Did, yes, they are independent.

Comment: @Did, I was wrong. Please see the updated question description. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please do not modify drastically a question after some answers are posted. Instead, revert the changes and ask a new question.

Comment: @I see your point. I have reverted my edit. The new question is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/747857/relation-between-multivariate-probability-generating-function-and-univariate-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is independent,
$$
G(z_1,z_2)=E(z_1^{X_1-X_2}z_2^{X_1-X_3})=E((z_1z_2)^{X_1}z_1^{-X_2}z_2^{-X_3}),
$$
hence
$$
G(z_1,z_2)=g_1(z_1z_2)g_2(z_1^{-1})g_3(z_2^{-1}).
$$