# relation between multivariate probability generating function and univariate ones

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, generating-functions

Suppose I have two independent integer random variables $X_1$, $X_2$ (with constraint that $X_1+X_2\le N,0\le X_1\le N,0\le X_2\le N$), with probability generating functions $g_1(z)$, $g_2(z)$. Now I have a joint-distribution $P(X_1-X_2,2X_1+X_2-N)$, whose probability generating function is $G(z_1,z_2)$. $N$ is a constant.

What is the relation between $G(z_1,z_2)$ and $g_1(z)$, $g_2(z)$?

The following question is related but not the same:
[multivariate probability generating function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746344/multivariate-probability-generating-function)

Comment: The constraints tend not to marry well with independence;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$
G(z_1,z_2)=E(z_1^{X_1-X_2}z_2^{2X_1+X_2-N})=z_2^{-N}E((z_1z_2^2)^{X_1}(z_1^{-1}z_2)^{X_2}).
$$
Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent,
$$
G(z_1,z_2)=z_2^{-N}g_1(z_1z_2^2)g_2(z_1^{-1}z_2).
$$
This does not use the constraints.